# Filter in pie chart not working SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

For some reason, I am unable to get the filter functionality to work properly. I have 4 options labeled as A, B, C, D. Then I have the values being represented in the chart are points.

I go to Chart Properties and then the Data tab. I go to category and select Edit and then to Filters.

Here I select
Expression as =Fields!options.Value
Operator as =
Value as A

I want to make a pie graph of just Option A against the whole. When I use the settings above, the graph does not even show. If I take out the filter, the graph shows all 4 Options

```
I tried value
<br>=A <br>
"A" <br>
="A" <br>But nothing works.
```

Can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this would be to put your options into a parameter and then set the filter for the graph to equate to the parameter selected.